# How to use php's popen(cmd,"w") so output appears in browser?

Tags: php, popen

I'm trying to use popen() with the "w" flag so PHP can pump some text into a command, and have the command's HTML output end up in the web browser.

But the output of the command which should be going to stdout is being entirely lost.

I reduced the problem to this simple script, using cat(1) in place of my actual command:

```
<?php

print("<PRE>\n--- START POPEN\n");

$fp = popen("cat -n 2>&1", "w");
fwrite($fp, "Line one\nLine two\nLine three\n\nLine five\n");
pclose($fp);

print("--- END POPEN\n</PRE>\n");
?>
```

What I expect to see in the browser is:

```
--- START POPEN
     1  Line one
     2  Line two
     3  Line three
     4  
     5  Line five
--- END POPEN
```

(The numbers being added by cat's -n flag.) And that IS what I get if I run the script from the unix shell. But in the browser I just get:

```
--- START POPEN
--- END POPEN
```

The cat command's output is just.. lost?

I tried adding flush() and ob_flush() above the popen(), but to no effect.
Nothing's appearing in the apache error.log.

If I change the cat command to redirect its output to a tmp file and reload the page, cat's output *does* appear in the tmp file, e.g.

```
BEFORE: $fp = popen("cat -n 2>&1", "w");
 AFTER: $fp = popen("cat -n > /var/tmp/foo.out 2>&1", "w");
```

This shows me popen() and cat(1) are both working (cat is found in PATH) and data is pumping through the pipe correctly.

I'm used to expecting popen()'s stdout to be mixed nicely with the application's own (C, Perl, Python..), so am I missing something extra needed for this to work in PHP?

**Server=Linux, Apache=2.4, php=7.x.**

Comment: I stopped using php 5 years ago. Don't remember anything. But, `fwrite` writes to file, right? Then you should read the file and print it.

Comment: @SagarV php's fwrite() is like C's; it writes data to a "handle". A handle can be associated with a file (via fopen()), pipes (via popen()), sockets, and other things. I could definitely use fwrite() to write to a tmp file, run the command with system() to read that tmp file, letting stdout go to the browser, and then remove the tmp file. But tmp files are messy and can be left behind if the user closes the tab while the operation is running, etc. popen() is the right thing to use to avoid them with a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The note of [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) manual says:

> If you're looking for bi-directional support (two-way), use [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Comment: Not only good, `cat` [concatenate files, or standard input, to standard output.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat), so it use both ways if you don't provide an input file like your example did.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I don't follow shingo. It sounds like you're saying because I'm using cat I need a bidirectional pipe? No; 'cat -n' is being used here to read stdin and write to stdout. popen() with "w" should arrange things so stdin of the command reads from the pipe that php fwrite() provides, and stdout should be the same stdout as PHP's. When run from the shell the script runs as expected, the output included with PHPs print()s: fwrite -> pipe -> cat -n -> stdout -> tty. That's expected. But under apache: fwrite -> pipe -> cat -n -> stdout -> ?LOST?.

Comment: Php has 2 mode CLI and CGI. In CLI mode, output stream is stdout, same as cat, that's why you can see cat's output. In CGI mode, output stream for print/echo/... is another output buffer, print->php://output, fwrite->php://stdout, they are different in this mode.

Comment: You can check [php io stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks shingo -- I'll look into that.
Just did some experiments running a long command (sleep 60) in the write mode popen(),  and inspecting with lsof(1); found stdout + stderr of the child process is attached to /dev/null..! Argh. Excerpt of 'lsof -p <child_pid>':
`sleep   23615 www-data    0r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 2971346 pipe`
`sleep   23615 www-data    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0   14964 /dev/null`
`sleep   23615 www-data    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0   14964 /dev/null`
Note the two /dev/null's for 1w (stdout) and 2w (stderr).

Comment: OK, looks like a workaround is to simply run the original php script with system("php foo.php"); from /another/ PHP script. That seems to work fine, allowing popen() in write mode to work normally.